# Fetching a single sheet from a Google Spreadsheet as bytes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, export-to-excel

I'm trying to retrieve a single sheet from a google spreadsheet in excel format, I have all the access setup correctly and can run different google sheet v4 api functions on it.

I wanted to use the Google::Apis::SheetsV4::SheetsService::copy_spreadsheet function to copy a single sheet as mentioned in the Ruby example here - https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.sheets/copyTo

This is my code -

```
service = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::SheetsService.new
service.client_options.application_name = APPLICATION_NAME
service.authorization = authorize

spreadsheet_id = "<passing my spreadsheet id here>"
gid = "<setting this as my sheet id from the spreadsheet>"
request = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::CopySheetToAnotherSpreadsheetRequest.new(
        destination_spreadsheet_id: "0",
      )
response1 = service.copy_spreadsheet(spreadsheet_id,gid,request)

puts response1.to_json
```

This always fails with the following error -

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/google-apis-core-0.4.2/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:229:in `check_status': badRequest: Invalid destinationSpreadsheetId [0] (Google::Apis::ClientError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/google-apis-core-0.4.2/lib/google/apis/core/api_command.rb:134:in `check_status'
```

Would be great if someone can help me on how to use this properly, also if there's a better way to download/export a single sheet from a spreadsheet in Ruby let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Answer for question 1

> This always fails with the following error -

> ```
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/google-apis-core-0.4.2/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:229:in `check_status': badRequest: Invalid destinationSpreadsheetId [0] (Google::Apis::ClientError)
>   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/google-apis-core-0.4.2/lib/google/apis/core/api_command.rb:134:in `check_status'
> ```

> Would be great if someone can help me on how to use this properly,

When I saw your error message and your script, I thought that `destination_spreadsheet_id: "0",` is not correct. In this case, please set the destination Spreadsheet ID. When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

```
src_spreadsheet_id = "###" # Please set the source Spreadsheet ID.
src_sheet_id = "###" # Please set the sheet ID of the source Spreadsheet.
dst_spreadsheet_id = "###" # Please set the destination Spreadsheet ID.

request = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::CopySheetToAnotherSpreadsheetRequest.new(
  destination_spreadsheet_id: dst_spreadsheet_id,
)
response1 = service.copy_spreadsheet(src_spreadsheet_id,src_sheet_id,request)
puts response1.to_json
```

#### Answer for question 2

> I'm trying to retrieve a single sheet from a google spreadsheet in excel format, I have all the access setup correctly and can run different google sheet v4 api functions on it.

> also if there's a better way to download/export a single sheet from a spreadsheet in Ruby let me know.

In this case, how about the following sample script? In this script, a XLSX data including the specific sheet is downloaded using the endpoint of `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{spreadsheetId}/export?format=xlsx&gid={sheetId}`. So, please set your Spreadsheet ID and sheet ID to the URL. And, in this case, the access token is retrieved from `service` you are using.

```
url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{spreadsheetId}/export?format=xlsx&gid={sheetId}'
filename = 'sample.xlsx' # Please set the saved filename.

access_token = service.request_options.authorization.access_token
open(
  url,
  "Authorization" => "Bearer " + access_token,
  :redirect => true
) do |file|
  open(filename, "w+b") do |out|
    out.write(file.read)
  end
end
```

- When this script is run, the specific sheet of `sheetId` of `spreadsheetId` is downloaded as a XLSX data and save it.
- This script uses `require "open-uri"`.

##### Note:

- When the Spreadsheet is downloaded as a XLSX data, when an error related to the scope, please add `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` to the scopes and reauthorize again. By this, the script works.

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.sheets.copyTo](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.sheets/copyTo)

Comment: Thanks for your response, using the approach you used in answer 1, I've done the same exact code but setting destination to a random so that I can read the spreadsheet in code. Is that not an intended functionality of the copy spreadsheet function. Also I'll be trying out the second approach you mentioned.

Comment: @Osy Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your reply. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Is there a way to use copyTo but also preserve the format of the xlsx file? I have a case where I want to preserve its format but for fields with formulas I want to take the numeric value instead of the formula to avoid any reference issues

Comment: @Osy Thank you for replying. About your new 3rd question of `Is there a way to use copyTo but also preserve the format of the xlsx file? I have a case where I want to preserve its format but for fields with formulas I want to take the numeric value instead of the formula to avoid any reference issues `, I would like to support you. But, you have already requested 2 questions. So, I would like to recommend resolving your initial question. If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: I've just marked it as resolved

Comment: @Osy Thank you for your response. I would like to support your new question. So, can you post `Is there a way to use copyTo but also preserve the format of the xlsx file? I have a case where I want to preserve its format but for fields with formulas I want to take the numeric value instead of the formula to avoid any reference issues` as a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of the solution.